# What to connect/link my DDiscMaster2Events to for drive change events. Microsoft COM objects

Tags: c++, com, mfc, mingw

I am tying to implement Microsoft's COM objects DDiscMaster2Events on mingw to get disk drive change events. I have not been able to find any examples of this. I already got DDiskFormat2DataEvents to work so I expect it to be similar to that. In DDiskFormat2DataEvents I had to connect my DDiskFormat2DataEvents with a IDiskFormat2Data to get the events. This is normally done with the AfxConnectionAdvise method. What com object do I need to connect my DDiscMaster2Events events sink to, to receive disk change events? A Visual Studio c++ example should answer my question. Thanks

Comment: Hmya, this is where MinGW peters out.  The project has a high bar for patches they accept.  Using Open Source principles, they only add headers for things that are publicly documented.  Intricate COM object models like IMAPI are not, Microsoft docs assume availability of the SDK headers or a late-bound scripting engine interface through IDispatch.  Details like the dispid of methods or the exact order of the methods in the v-table require the headers.  You are just plain using the wrong tooling to get this going.

Comment: @Hans If I can find an example in Visual c++ I think I can adapt it. The mingw part is not the hold up at this point, it is how to connect the DDiscMaster2Events event sink. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

There is some information about how to receive COM events in this article [COM Connection Points](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163361.aspx) by Thottam R. Sriram.

Based on its contents, somethink like this might work for you:

```
#include <imapi2.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>

class DiscMaster2EventsSink : public DDiscMaster2Events {
  public:
    STDMETHOD(NotifyDeviceAdded)(IDispatch *object, BSTR uniqueId)
    {
      std::cout << "NotifyDeviceAdded(...)\n";
      return S_OK;
    }

    STDMETHOD(NotifyDeviceRemoved)(IDispatch *object, BSTR uniqueId)
    {
      std::cout << "NotifyDeviceRemoved(...)\n";
      return S_OK;
    }

  public:
    // The uninteresting stuff follows...

    DiscMaster2EventsSink()
      : m_refCount(1)
    {
    }

    STDMETHOD(QueryInterface)(REFIID riid, void **ppv)
    {
      *ppv = NULL;

      if (riid == IID_IUnknown)
        *ppv = static_cast<void*>(static_cast<IUnknown*>(this));
      else if (riid == IID_IDispatch)
        *ppv = static_cast<void*>(static_cast<IDispatch*>(this));
      else if (riid == __uuidof(DDiscMaster2Events))
        *ppv = static_cast<void*>(static_cast<DDiscMaster2Events*>(this));

      if (*ppv) {
        AddRef();
        return S_OK;
      }

      return E_NOINTERFACE;
    }

    STDMETHOD_(ULONG, AddRef)()
    {
      return InterlockedIncrement(&m_refCount);
    }

    STDMETHOD_(ULONG, Release)()
    {
      ULONG result = InterlockedDecrement(&m_refCount);
      if (result == 0)
        delete this;
      return result;
    }

    STDMETHOD(GetIDsOfNames)(REFIID riid, LPOLESTR *rgszNames, UINT cNames, LCID lcid, DISPID *rgDispId)
    {
      return E_NOTIMPL;
    }

    STDMETHOD(GetTypeInfo)(UINT iTInfo, LCID lcid, ITypeInfo **ppTInfo)
    {
       return E_NOTIMPL;
    }

    STDMETHOD(GetTypeInfoCount)(UINT *pctinfo)
    {
      *pctinfo = 0;
      return S_OK;
    }

    STDMETHOD(Invoke)(DISPID dispIdMember, REFIID riid, LCID lcid, WORD wFlags, DISPPARAMS *pDispParams,
      VARIANT *pVarResult, EXCEPINFO *pExcepInfo, UINT *puArgErr)
    {
      return E_NOTIMPL;
    }

  private:
    ULONG m_refCount;
};

int main()
{
  HRESULT hr;

  hr = CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINIT_MULTITHREADED);
  assert(SUCCEEDED(hr));

  IDiscMaster2* pDiscMaster2;
  hr = CoCreateInstance(__uuidof(MsftDiscMaster2), NULL, CLSCTX_ALL, __uuidof(IDiscMaster2), (void**)&pDiscMaster2);
  assert(SUCCEEDED(hr));

  IConnectionPointContainer* pCPC;
  hr = pDiscMaster2->QueryInterface(IID_IConnectionPointContainer, (void**)&pCPC);
  assert(SUCCEEDED(hr));

  IConnectionPoint* pCP;
  hr = pCPC->FindConnectionPoint(IID_DDiscMaster2Events, &pCP);
  assert(SUCCEEDED(hr));

  DiscMaster2EventsSink* pSink = new DiscMaster2EventsSink();

  IUnknown* pSinkUnk;
  hr = pSink->QueryInterface(IID_IUnknown, (void**)&pSinkUnk);
  assert(SUCCEEDED(hr));

  DWORD dwAdvise;
  hr = pCP->Advise(pSinkUnk, &dwAdvise);
  assert(SUCCEEDED(hr));

  std::cout << "OK...\n";
  std::cin.get();

  pSinkUnk->Release();
  pSink->Release();
  pCP->Release();
  pCPC->Release();
  pDiscMaster2->Release();
  CoUninitialize();
  return 0;
}
```

It compiles and runs fine for me as far as I can see (S_OK all the way), but I cannot see any events - possibly because I doesn't have an external optical drive to mess with to create any device add/remove events.

(Also obviously with some C++ COM helper class it would be much nicer.)

Hopefully it might still help you, perhaps with a few changes even under MinGW.

Comment: I was really close. I was able to finish the implementation, but it does not seem to work. When I add or remove a usb cd/dvd drive nothing prints from NotifyDeviceAdded or NotifyDeviceRemoved methods.

Comment: Hmm, does it work at all? E.g. when you try it in some other, perhaps simple scripting language with proper COM event support?

Comment: I built the above example in Visual Studio and it does not print anything to the screen when removing or adding a usb cd/dvd drive from the system. Either something is set up wrong or this class catches different events then I think.

Comment: Yes, I see. I wanted to say that you might try the same in e.g. a WScript first, to see if the problem is in the C++ code, or in the event not being sent at all. I found this page where the event registration seems very simple: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366443.aspx